# Find and delete local user on several clients

Tags: powershell, user-accounts, workgroup

I have some clients in the domain and some not.
I need to know how to retrieve on which clients it is present a specific local user and then delete it.
With a GPO is pretty easy for domain clients, but what about the non-domain ones?
I know the Powershell commands *Get-LocalUser* and *Delete-LocalUser*, but I would prefer not to launch it on every single PC.
Do you know any kind of script that could help ?

Thanks

Comment: Are the non-domain machines in the same network as the domain-joined machines?

Comment: Unfortunately not, they are located in different countries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enable PSRemoting ([workgroup mode](https://www.bing.com/search?q=powershell%20remoting%20workgroup&form=ANNTH1&refig=79eb6959bba1462ea4f9ee0cf92ce88b&sp=-1&pq=powershell%20remoting%20workgro&sc=2-27&qs=n&sk=&cvid=79eb6959bba1462ea4f9ee0cf92ce88b)) on those non-Domain machines, and then you can use remoting to do this and those systems must have the latest PSv5 or have the module for local user management from the MS powershellgallery.com.

You are still going to have to touch each of those machines to set up remoting.

• [Enable PowerShell Remoting on a standalone (workgroup) computer](https://4sysops.com/archives/enable-powershell-remoting-on-a-standalone-workgroup-computer)

• [PowerShell remoting between two workgroup machines](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wmi/2009/07/24/powershell-remoting-between-two-workgroup-machines)

• [PowerShell PS Remoting Between Standalone Workgroup Computers](http://vcloud-lab.com/entries/active-directory/powershell-ps-remoting-between-standalone-workgroup-computers)

• [PowerShell remoting between two workgroup machines](https://posh2scripting.wordpress.com/2013/06/07/powershell-remoting-between-two-workgroup-machines)

Read each article so you know all the details, but in a snippet, it's:

```
### Remote Computer

NetConnectionProfile -NetworkCategory Private
Enable-PSRemoting -SkipNetworkProfileCheck -Force
Set-NetFirewallRule –Name "WINRM-HTTP-In-TCP-PUBLIC" –RemoteAddress Any


### Local computer

# Review teh trusted host file
Get-Item WSMan:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts

# Set the trusted a specific target
Set-Item WSMan:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts -Value "10.0.2.33" -Force

# Or for several hosts if you don't want to specify them individually
Set-Item WSMan:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts -Value "*" -Force

# Connect to a host
Enter-PSSession -ComputerName 10.0.2.33 -Credential $Credentials
```

There are a few PowerShell commands you can run [without remoting being enabled](https://www.bing.com/search?q=powershell%20remoting%20without%20enabling%20remoting&form=ANNTH1&refig=51b5842f836f447683b82e71c51fc584&sp=-1&pq=powershell%20remoting%20without%20enabling%20remot&sc=0-42&qs=n&sk=&cvid=51b5842f836f447683b82e71c51fc584):

• [Work Remotely with Windows PowerShell without using Remoting or WinRM](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff699046.aspx)

```
Get-WinEvent
Get-Counter
Get-EventLog
Clear-EventLog
Write-EventLog
Limit-EventLog
Show-EventLog
New-EventLog
Remove-EventLog
Get-WmiObject
Get-Process
Get-Service
Set-Service
Get-HotFix
Restart-Computer
Stop-Computer
Add-Computer
Remove-Computer
Rename-Computer
Reset-ComputerMachinePassword
```

Or use the MS Sysinternals PSExec.exe tool:

[Sysinternals Suite - Windows Sysinternals | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/sysinternals-suite)

Comment: Thanks a lot mate.

Comment: No worries, just know, for the most part, any cmdlets that have a -ComputerName   [Get-Command -CommandType Cmdlet | Where-Object { $PSItem.parameters.keys -match 'ComputerName'} | Out-GridView -PassThru -Title 'Available cmdlets which has a specific parameter']   parameter can be used without remoting enabled in the WMI namespace, but once you get into the Invoke-*, one needs to be in the local admin group on the remote host, domain joined or not.